# htaccess - passing random variables dynamically

Tags: .htaccess

My current htaccess file (courtesy of @anubhava) is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# load index.php by default
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteBase /

# remove trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L]

# for all other requests load room.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|anonymity|similarity|inconspicuous)
RewriteRule ^((?!(index|room)\.php).+)$ room.php?u=$1 [L,NC]
```

The way it works now is if someone goes to www.example.com they are directed to `index.php`. If they go to www.example.com/anythingelse they are redirected to `room.php`

I have 3 additional variables that can be passed by the user at anytime. They might only use 1 of them or maybe all 3 of them. The three additional variables are

```
redirect
panic
timeout
```

If I were to use all three in the url it would look something like

`http://www.example.com/this?panic=0&timeout=3&redirect=google.com`

but as I said they may only pass some of these, so another variation could be

`http://www.example.com/this?timeout=3&redirect=google.com`

is it possible to be able to determine dynamically (in no particular order) which variables were chosen and be able to pass them to `room.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass them along by using the `QSA` flag in your last rule:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!(index|room)\.php).+)$ room.php?u=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

That'll pass the query string along to `room.php`.